# Why is my Netlify function throwing an error trying to JSON.parse() the event object?

Tags: json, parsing, serverless, netlify

I am trying to implement SendGrid through a Netlify serveless functions, however every time after submitting the form the function throws this error:

```
{
  "errorType": "SyntaxError",
  "errorMessage": "Unexpected token a in JSON at position 1",
  "trace": [
     "SyntaxError: Unexpected token a in JSON at position 1",
     "    at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)",
     "    at Runtime.exports.handler (/var/task/src/functions/sendmail.js:5:44)",
     "    at Runtime.handleOnce (/var/runtime/Runtime.js:66:25)"
  ]
}
```

I have no idea what is wrong as from Netlify docs the `event.body` is a JSON string so why `JSON.parse()` is not working?

[Github](https://github.com/jamborski-dev/valpol-autos/blob/master/functions/sendmail.js)